# select max date with given year and month

Tags: postgresql

let say I have a column named `report_date` with data type of `date` and I want to select the max date for a given year and month, for example the date is:

```
+------------+
|report_date |
+------------+
|2017-10-25  |
|2017-10-12  |
|2017-10-28  |
|2017-10-23  |
+------------+
```

I want to select max date of October 2017.

honestly I have no idea how to get the max date. any help would be really apreciate.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With extract:

```
select max(report_date)
from the_table
where (extract(year from report_date), extract(month from report_date)) = (2017,10);
```

Or with a range query:

```
select max(report_date)
from the_table
where report_date >= date '2017-10-01'
  and report_date < date '2017-11-01'
```

Or with string comparison

```
select max(report_date)
from the_table
where to_char(report_date,'yyyy-mm') = '2017-10';
```

Or with date_trunc()

```
select max(report_date)
from the_table
where date_trunc('month', report_date)::date = date '2017-10-01';
```